# Characterization of graphs with vertex-connectivity equal to edge-connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Are there any attempts to characterize (simple, finite) **graphs with vertex-connectivity $\kappa$ equal edge-connectivity $\kappa'$**?

In general, $\kappa(G)\leq \kappa'(G)\leq \delta(G)$ where $\delta(G)$ denotes the minimum degree of $G$.

If characterizations are not known (quite possible), I would appreciate lists of widely known necessary or sufficient conditions. The following is a sufficient condition I found in the literature.

If $G$ is a **connected edge-transitive graph**, then $\kappa(G)=\kappa'(G)=\delta(G)$  (see Corollay 1A in [1]).

[1] *Watkins, M. E.*, [**Connectivity of transitive graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(70)80005-9), J. Comb. Theory 8, 23-29 (1970). [ZBL0185.51702](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0185.51702).

Comment: What kind of characterization are you looking for? All these quantities have already good certificates. Moreover, you can take any 2-connected graph and add a new vertex with two neighbors, and this gives a graph where $\kappa = \kappa' = 2$, so there is not much structure to capture here.

Comment: @Guyslain. I am interested in necessary/sufficient conditions to ensure that $\kappa(G)=\kappa'(G)$ for graphs $G$ that belong to **large graph classes** (such as regular graphs, bipartite graphs, planar graphs, etc.).